# Running Tor in /opt

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, debian

I'm looking at using the Tor browser bundle, and the instructions have one run the bundle as a normal user (in my case, on Debian Jessie).  This would seem to expose the Tor files to tampering in a way that is not the case with iceweasel.

Q1:  are my concerns misplaced?

I've tried to run Tor inside of /opt with a softlink to /usr/local/bin/start-tor-browser, but unless I assign "my user:my user" to the entire "/opt/torfolder" I get a permission error.  There is code to stop Tor running as root which I'd prefer not to comment out, but regardless I don't think that is the main problem at the moment.

Q: is there a "best practice" for running Tor as a normal user, but for protecting the Tor files from user tampering with permissions?

Q: What are the benefits/downsides of using visudo?

Thanks!

Comment: In what ways are the Tor files exposed to tampering if running as a non-root user? (And how does Iceweasel prevent this?)

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for the question.  My sense is installed linux apps like iceweasel files are stored in folders with root:root permissions, and  libraries/application files have root:root permissions.  The Tor Browser Bundle is meant to run in a user account, with regular user permissions, so my assumption is that it is easier for those files to be vulnerable to malware/user mistakes.  If so, am looking for a way to set up Tor like iceweasel where Tor folders/files have root:root but can be run by regular users.  Not sure TBB allows this easily given how it is configured to work.

Answer (score 2):

In complement of Alexey's detailed answer, let me add the following.
As [indicated, for instance, here](https://cialu.net/install-tor-browser-on-linux-and-set-up-a-launcher/), the simpler way to install `tor browser` in `/opt` on Linux is probably the following:

1. Download a bundle at https://www.torproject.org/download/#downloads
2. (optional, but recommended) Check the signature (https://support.torproject.org/tbb/how-to-verify-signature/)
3. Extract the file, for instance with

   ```
   tar -xvfJ tor-browser-linux64-9.0_en-US.tar.xz.asc
   ```
4. **As root**, move the files to `/opt`, using for instance

   ```
   mv tor-browser_en-US /opt
   ```
5. Finally, **as a normal user**, run the program with

   ```
       cd /opt/tor-browser_en-US/
       ./start-tor-browser.desktop
   ```

and you can even add to that latter command `--register-app` at the end, to be able to run the program from anywhere (i.e., to add it to the applications in your menu, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

So - here are your answers, step by step:

- **Q1** Tor has no folder-hardcode in it's entire source, and if you're about to use `/opt/tordir` or *anything else that is physically reachable in your FileSystem API* - it's totally OK. Just **make sure** that you will make it *actually reachable* by issuing `chown -R tor-user:tor-user-primary-group /path/to/your/tordir` and making it referenced as `DataDirectory /full/path/to/your/tordir/from/the/very/top` **and** corresponding values with full path too: `GeoIPFile`,`GeoIPv6File`,`PidFile`. And the magic goes on! Use `User tor-user` as the **very last line** in your `torrc`. That's it - I'm running Tor from it's dedicated and non-standart folder too.
- **Q2** Make a separate directory for Tor(look Q1 answer), use `/etc/torrc` owned by root **only** and run it as a regular dedicated user. Additional file security is - actually - not required strictly, *but of course a UMASK 077 is in order* **system-wide**, or don't speak about a filesystem security on that host at all. Extra level of defense - above umask 077 - if you will need it - I'd recommend you AppArmor, used it in Ubuntu and in Debian. Really simple and powerful tool if you need some additional hardening.
- **Q3** it's a native part of `sudo` toolset, so it's totally fine to use it: because only root is able to use it and even read a sudoers file. But as in any case of include-configs, **do check that not a byte is included from either directories or files**: all the sudo permissions **must** reside on *one single file*. And if you'll have a root account breached - your server is lost regardless of OS you're using(except MS-DOS, pehaps)

Feel free to ask more questions - I'll be glad to help!